# Fatal error in my WP

Tags: array, fatal-error

Everytime I try to login my WP, this fatal error appears and I have no idea of what happened and how to solve. Can anybody help me out? I've got "zero" knowledge in programming and coding.

This is what appears to me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in
   /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin/inc/user-experience-tracking.php:92 Stack trace:
#0 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin/inc/user-experience-tracking.php(476): mm_clm_log('content_draft', Object(WP_Post))
#1 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): mm_ux_log_content_status('draft', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#2 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(3965): do_action('transition_post...', 'draft', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#5 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(3425): wp_transition_post_status('draft', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#6 /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/includes/admin/class-am-notification.php(143): wp_insert_po
in /home1/tenhacon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin/inc/user-experience-tracking.php on line 92
```

Comment: I would contact the people who built the mojo marketplace plugin and let them know this is happening so they can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Go to your plugins dir `wp-content/plugins/` and rename `mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin` folder.

This will deactivate `mojo-marketplace` and won't throw you an error when you try to login.

Then you can contact with their support and solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help Kuliraj. Is there a specific name I should rename this folder?

Comment: No, as soon as it's named differently, it will be deactivated, the name itself does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin` plugin, you can disable or update this plugin.

Or you can fix this issue in the plugin.

Comment: Hi Mostafa,thank you for your answer. How do I do that if I can't reach my panel or my dashboard? Everytime I try to login the message appears and I can't manage anything in my WP

Comment: You can rename this plugin in the server. the plugin will be disabled.

Comment: Is there a specif name to rename it?

Comment: When you rename this folder `mojo-marketplace-wp-plugin`, the plugin will be disabled automaticaly.